# What's the proof for $a-(b-c)=(a-b)\cup(a\cap c)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that: 
$$a-(b-c)=(a-b)\cup(a\cap c)$$

I do know that in $a-(b-c)$ that $x\in a$ and $x\notin b-c$.

And also I know in $(a-b)\cup(a\cap c)$ that either $x\in a$ and $x\notin b$ or $x\in a$ and $x\in c$ but something is missing and I'll be happy to get some help :)

Comment: For future reference, please refer to this post to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

It'll be easier for you to type, and easier for us to read.

Comment: The usual way to prove this kind of statements is to check that the first set is included in the second, and the second is included in the first. Your case makes no exception!

Answer (score 1):

> $x \in a \setminus (b \setminus c)$ is equivalent to "$x \in a$ and $x \notin b \setminus c$."

That's right. You then need to show that $x$ is either in $a \setminus b$ or $a \cap c$. Try handling the two cases $x \in c$ and $x \notin c$ separately.

> Suppose $x \in c$ as well. Since we already know $x \in a$, we have $x \in a \cap c$.

${}$

> Otherwise, $x \notin c$. Then we know $x \notin b$ as well (otherwise, we would have $x \in b \setminus c$, which would contradict our assumption $x \notin b\setminus c$). So, $x \in a$ and $x\notin b$, that is, $x \in a \setminus b$.

---

> $x \in (a \setminus b) \cup (a \cap c)$ is equivalent to "either $x \in a$ and $x \notin b$, or $x \in a$ and $x \in c$."

That's right. Again, try casework. First assume $x \in a$ and $x \notin b$, and show that this implies $x \in a \setminus (b \setminus c)$. Then handle the other case.

> If $x \in a$ and $x \notin b$, then clearly $x \notin b \setminus c$ holds as well. So $x \in a$ and $x \notin b \setminus c$, which is equivalent to $x \in a \setminus (b \setminus c)$.

${}$

> If $x \in a$ and $x \in c$, then $x \notin b \setminus c$ holds, and the same reasoning leads to $x \in a \setminus ( b \setminus c)$.

Answer (score 1):

From this expression −(−)=(−)∪(∩), you know that :

∈, the question here is wether ∈c or ∉c.

If ∈c :

Then you got that ∈ by hypothesis, and ∈, because you are getting rid off all elements of c in b you know that ∈ and ∈, because you re supposing that ∈.

If ∉c :

Then you got that ∈ and ∉b, this is a simple deduction from the assertion that was given to you.

Thus −(−)=(−)∪(∩) is True.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, element chase... and when stuck do cases.

Suppose $x \in a - (b-c)$.

Then $x \in a$ and $x \not \in b -c$.

Now either $x \in b$ or $x \not \in b$.

Case 1:  $x \in b$.  Now either $x \in c$ or $x \not \in c$.

Case 1a: if $x \in c$ then $x \in a$ and $x\in c$ so $x \in a\cap c$

So it is true that either $a \in a\cap c$ or $x \in a-b$ so $x \in (a-b)\cup (a \cap c)$.

Case 1b: if $x \not \in c$ then as $x \in b$ then $x \in b-c$ which is a contradiction.

Case 2: $x \not \in b$.  Then as $x \in a$ then $x\in a-b$ so it is true that either $a \in a\cap c$ or $x \in a-b$ so $x \in (a-b)\cup (a \cap c)$.

So $a-(b-c) \subset (a-b)\cup (a\cap c)$.

.....

Suppose $y \in (a-b) \cup (a\cap c)$.

Case 1:  $y \in a-b$.  Then $y \not \in b$ so $y \not \in b-c$. But $y \in a$ so $y \in a-(b-c)$.

Case 2:  $y \in a\cap c$.  So $y \in a$ but as $y \in c$ it can't be the case that $y\not \in c$ and $y \in b$.  So $y \not \in b-c$.  So $y\in a-(b-c)$.

So $(a-c)\cup (a\cap c) \subset a-(b-c)$.